# Can I tell the PI who has offered me a postdoc job that I have not decided yet waiting for other results

Tags: postdocs, job

I have got a postdoc job offer from a reputed University in Applied Mathematics. Now, I have given several postdoc interviews and some interviews are scheduled in the coming days. In such situation can I tell the PI (wherefrom I got the offer) that I have not decided yet as I have some other interviews scheduled in the future. I have heard that accepting multiple offers is not a good thing.

Comment: Just thank them and tell them you will respond before the deadline in the offer letter.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: There is no deadline given. Can I politely ask them ?

Comment: Did you receive a formal offer?  Usually these are signed by a high ranking administrator.  If not, you might be wise to ask for one.  Then you will know what the deadline is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right about not accepting multiple offers. But that isn't the same as not considering multiple offers.

Unless you have a special relationship with the PI you don't actually owe him or her an explanation of why you are waiting. It would, however, do you good if you could give a date, not too far in the future, by which you will let him/her know.

Of course, it is possible that the offer could be withdrawn, rules permitting, but if you wait to accept you can't control that.

I wouldn't probably say I was awaiting other offers, or give a false reason instead. It is enough to say that you aren't yet quite ready to make a decision on such a big step. Yes, that sort of thing is a bit of hedging, but probably called for, since you are actually hedging.

But don't put them off too long.

Comment: Is it ok to say to the PI that I need to talk to my advisor.

Comment: I might, rather, put it that you are in discussions with your advisor. You are allowed to keep your reasoning to yourself. The PI is allowed to make independent decision.